# How can I sell items for a higher profit?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've just started playing and am currently level 12.

I would like to know if it's possible to sell items, particularly more expensive ones, such as dragon bones, for closer to the original value.

All the stores I've seen purchase the items for too little. Is there any way I can sell it for more?

Comment: I question whether that is a true duplicate. The original is in effect a "partial answer". OP wants to sell items at a higher price, where the original asks for how to sell at a higher price **using only speechcraft points, ie, no merchant favour,no perks, nothing else to assist a higher price. **

Comment: @Timelord64 Seeing as how Community has closed this question, that means the asked found their answer in the dupe, so I'd say this is closed correctly.

Comment: That does not make sense, to me, @Frank. I'm unfamiliar with the purpose of Community, but I have posed the same argument to a Community closed question, before, to see it reopened, the next day.

Comment: It makes sense if the user has since deleted their account.. probably something I couldn't see from here. My argument still stands, though, for what is being asked, that is not a duplicate; more a partial answer

Comment: @Timelord64 When someone marks something as a dupe it gives the asked a little pop-up asking, "does this answer your question?", with a yes or no. If the asker clicks yes, Community closes it for the asked. That tells me that the question asked is a dupe. Unless you read into technicalities, where it might not be an *exact* dupe, but close enough for the asker.

Comment: @Timelord64 - Further to what Frank says - the OP of this question doesn't have closing privileges yet, thus the actual "close" action is handled by the "Community User" - which in essence is just a user representing the system's processes. If Scott had enough reputation to vote for closure, his name would be shown instead of 'Community'.